# Error: Cannot convert value of type 'String.Type' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

```
struct DownloadButton: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: DownloadViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            viewModel.downloadVideo(url: String) <<here
        }) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.down")
                Text("Download")
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(8)
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a MacOS application to download YT Videos, and have run into a bit of a problem. I am asking for input in ContentView I just want it here where the "String" is. But I am unable to do so.

I tried to google it but couldn't find anything useful. I am still a beginner at this.

Comment: What did you write `viewModel.downloadVideo(url: **(Error)**)` here before the error? Did you write `String`? You need I guess a real String value, not the class name?

Comment: @Larme i posted the full code, sorry about that.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

In `DownloadButton` you are passing the type of `String` as the url parameter:

```
struct DownloadButton: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: DownloadViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            viewModel.downloadVideo(url: String) // <<<<< HERE
        }) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.down")
                Text("Download")
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(8)
        }
    }
}
```

You need to pass an actual `String` instance as your view model's `downloadVideo` method is expecting a `String` parameter:

```
func downloadVideo(url: String)
```

For example:

```
viewModel.downloadVideo(url: "http://foo")
```

Comment: Should probably give an example e.g. `viewModel.downloadVideo(url: "http://foo")`

Comment: @JeremyP Good idea. I have edited my answer to include your example.

Comment: Can't upvote you, unfortunately. The one you already had was me.